# What are the differences between Stack Overflow and Cross Validated?

Tags: support, scope

I wonder what the differences are between Stack Overflow and Cross Validated (the stats Stack Exchange).

How can I figure out in which one of them I should post my question?

Comment: What's this "cross validated"?

Comment: This: http://stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic and http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: What is it now? Cross Validated? Stack Exchange in general? CS SE? And to note: Stack Exchange in itself isn't a site. It's a network of sites.

Comment: I really got confused ! I should say crossvalidated or stackexchange?

Comment: If you're talking about the site Cross Validated, then say that. If you talk about the network of sites in general, say Stack Exchange. But in the latter case your question wouldn't make much sense.

Comment: I am talking about `http://stats.stackexchange.com/`

Comment: I don't understand this question. What do you think the _similarities_ are? What's causing you confusion between them? There's almost no overlap.

Comment: @JoshCaswell There's enough overlap that stats.stackechange.com is one of the default migration targets in the close reason menu. A lot of users have questions arising from using R that they think is a programming question, but is really a stats question (and vice versa).

Comment: I see, @joran; that seems [to be a recent addition to the list](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234294/bridge-moderators-and-an-increasing-trend-of-so-to-cv-migration-worthy-questions), and it's been a while since I've voted to migrate anything.

Comment: Why so many negatives !!! I just asked a question.

Comment: The topics of the two sites are clear enough, but I can see why someone might wonder whether to post to SO rather than CV. There are a lot more people on SO than on CV, and a lot of same people who frequent CV also frequent SO. So maybe the question might be framed as one of when to post, for example, a machine learning question on SO. Also, a lot of the difficulties a programmer might face trying to implement a machine learning algorithm might be related more to more general matters in programming.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The site descriptions say enough:

- Cross Validated is a question and answer site for people interested in statistics, machine learning, data analysis, data mining, and data visualization.
- Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers.

So, questions about statistics and data belong on CV, questions about programming issues belong on SO.

Comment: that is what i looking for. thanks.

Comment: @Cina For a complete list of all *sites* on the Stack Exchange *Network* see http://stackexchange.com/sites

Comment: but, why most of question about machine learning implementation are in Overflow?

Comment: Sites can have a small overlap in scope. And SO is the most active site within the network that exists far longer than CV.